# how can i send secure data from one app to another in android?

Tags: android

in android I want to pass data (4-5 strings) in a **secure** way (so broadcast is not an option) from another app to my app, so only my app could read that inforrmation.
what I need is somehow like the android notification - all apps can post notifications but only android (and the app that post it) can read that notification.
how can I do it? which method is the simplest to do it?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Secure against what? (or who?)

Comment: Secure from what? From other apps? From a dedicated user with a debugger on a rooted device?

Comment: edit my original post to a more specific request

Comment: @Royi Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used service for that
in that way the other apps can send the data direcly to the service

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the encryption libraries available.

http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have the chance to use the same user ID in both apps, the private mode of shared preferences could be an option. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)

Answer (score 0):

A [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) secured by a permission might fit.

Answer (score 0):

You can send encrypted data format through Intent like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setComponent(newComponentName("packageName","activityPackageName"));
intent.putExtra("encryptedData", "EncrptedData");
startActivity(intent);
```